# Android. How to create a directory in the root of internal storage

Tags: java, android

I need to create a Folder in the root of the internal storage, in order to create/store some files with information about the apps. Most solutions I found, are teaching how to create directories in external storage or in the apps directory.

For some reason, I wish I able to create folder in the root directory of the internal storage once I launch my apps.

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android security mechanism **would not allow** an app to manipulate file system out of its **security sandbox**. Instead you can manipulate the External Storage if you request the required permission.

Take a look at documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)